# WPF - MenuItem - Give a confirmation message on menu item check/uncheck

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, menuitem

In WPF, I have a MenuItem binded to settings and I would like to have a message box popup each time user click on this.

```
<MenuItem IsCheckable="True" Header="MyConfig" IsChecked="{Binding Source={x:Static res:Settings.Default}, 
               Path=MyConfigPath, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
```

What is the best way to do this (if possible without code behind)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the `Settings` class you're binding to is an auto-generated class that extends `ApplicationSettingsBase`, you could attach an event handler to [`SettingChanging`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.applicationsettingsbase.settingchanging(v=vs.110).aspx) and in that event handler show the confirmation dialog and if the user clicks "Cancel" you would need to set [`e.Cancel = true`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.settingchangingeventargs(v=vs.110).aspx).

Below is some psuedo-code that assumes `WpfInit()` will be called when you first show the WPF window:

```
private void WpfInit()
{
    Settings.Default.SettingChanging += Settings_SettingsChanging;
}

private void Settings_SettingsChanging(Object sender, SettingChangingEventArgs e) {
   var dlgResult = MessageBox.Show("Are you sure?", "Please Confirm...", MessageBoxButton.YesNo);
   if (dlgResult != MessageBoxResult.Yes) {
      e.Cancel = true;
      MessageBox.Show("Change cancelled");
   }
}
```

Notes:

- Don't forget to unhook your event handler when your WPF form closes `Settings.Default.SettingChanging -= Settings_SettingsChanging;`
- I feel that this code behind would make it most obvious to what you're intentions are to anyone that happens to read your code. Of course I'm sure there would be a way to avoid code behind, but IMHO avoiding code behind simply for the sake of avoiding code behind is not always best practice for code readability.

Answer (score 1):

> What is the best way to do this (if possible without code behind)?

That would be to bind the `Command` property of the `MenuItem` to an `ICommand` property of your view model and pop up the message box in the `Execute` method of the command:

```
<MenuItem IsCheckable="True" Header="MyConfig" IsChecked="{Binding Source={x:Static res:Settings.Default}, 
           Path=MyConfigPath, Mode=TwoWay}" Command="{Binding YourCommand}"/>
```

---

```
public DelegateCommand<object> YourCommand => new DelegateCommand<object>((arg) => MessageBox.Show(""));
```

Calling the blocking `MessageBox.Show` method in a view model is not a good idea though but that's another story: https://blog.magnusmontin.net/2013/04/20/implement-a-confirmation-dialog-in-wpf-with-mvvm-and-prism/